# On Linux,File created by which program?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have the same questions as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747335/is-it-possible-to-tell-which-application-created-a-file)
Only that my question is on the Linux platform

I have a directory in my folder
and I don't know which program has created it
Is it possible to know ?

Thanks

Comment: <a href="http://superuser.com/questions/33781/unix-historically-who-all-opened-a-particular-file/33879#33879">Yes, with auditd</a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer applies, unless the file itself has metadata like some .doc files and such that contains the information you cannot know what created the file (unless you create a kernel module to intercept block requests to create new files and check what application submitted the request but that is probably not what you want to do).

Comment: Thank you. Have you heard of such kernel modules ?

Comment: I've written some for performance statistics on Block I/O performance but you would have to run a custom kernel to do something like this.

Comment: Would such modules that monitor file creation activities have a big impact on the system performance? I'm a desktop user. Could you show me some hints on how to write such "simple" kernel modules ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @osager: http://superuser.com/questions/33781/unix-historically-who-all-opened-a-particular-file/33879#33879 - the functionality already exists.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same as in the previous question -- generally, no.

However, you can look at the owner and group of this directory; if the program that creates it is a daemon (service) process, it might be running under its own user / group and thus the files / directories created might have those ownerships.

What does this say?

```
ls -l /path/to/the/directory
```

Comment: unfortunately the owner is myself

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same as the one for question you linked. Linux doesn't store information about the creator of the file as far as which program did it. But, like the other answer said, you could create a monitor and record that information yourself.